# Where to store data retrieval code in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net

I am writing an application in ASP.NET MVC that interacts with the TeamCity C# API (unofficial).

I need to write some methods to get data e.g. the projects, build status, etc.

What I am still unsure about is where this should be stored in an MVC app? Would this be in the model?

Thanks!

Comment: Methods in controller, data that is manipulated by methods in model ^^

Comment: This can go anywhere, Your controller calling a repository, or just within the controller, Normally we separate the logics and try to make , as say, _thin controllers_, sometimes..

Comment: Thanks. I just need to make straightforward calls to get the data, not much "massaging" of the data needed, so I assume controllers alone is fine?